# Downvoted when you have 1 reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

I know that when you downvote, you lose 1 reputation, but when you get downvoted, you lose 2 reputation. Also, when you have at least 1 reputation, you can ask questions or provide answers. But what happens if you have 1 reputation and you get downvoted? Do you get -1 reputation? Or do you stay at 1 reputation, because otherwise, you can't do anything except for view questions?

Comment: Re: *when you downvote, you lose 1 reputation*. That's true, but you cannot downvote if you have less than [125 reputation points](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down). (BTW you lose reputation only if you downvote answer, not for downvoting questions.)

Comment: I meant that if you get downvoted, is your reputation total -1.

Answer (score 5):

In the [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), it is stated that reputation cannot go below 1. Furthermore, the decrements you mention are for downvoting answers. Downvoting a question takes smaller tolls.

Comment: ok, that explains a lot

Comment: Downvotes on questions are free.

Comment: @AmalMurali: yes, but advertising that seemed to be inviting a bear to dinner.

Comment: @robjohn: Haha, I forgot I'm on the Math.SE meta. -2 is definitely smaller than 0 :-P

Comment: @AmalMurali: I am not sure of your point, but a $0$ point decrease is a smaller toll than a $1$ point or $2$ point decrease.